# Why do people go by the Gra for the zman of kriat shema?

Tags: zemanim, shema

The Shema is a mitzvah d'oraita. So how is it that we can go by the later time of the Gra for sof zman kriat shema rather than the earlier time of the Magen Avraham?

It seems to me that this is a real Safek on a d'oraita which should be l'chumra, and no one should go by the zman of the Gra.

Can anyone explain why people are lenient?

Comment: Halachipedia, "Even though the primary time for the latest time of Shema is the third hour of the day according to the Gra, one should be strict for Magen Avraham to say before the third hour according to his calculation." So the question is why is the Gra's time primary?

Answer (score 3):

Those who are lenient are following later rabbis who decided the Halacha in favor of the Gra, so it is not a doubt for them. Disputes only represent a doubt if they are left unresolved.

Comment: If you provide sources you are more likely to get scored

Comment: Though it's worth noting that not all rabbis rule this way and some do say to be strict for both positions

Comment: Saying to be strict for both positions does not conflict with saying the bottom line opinion is like the lenient position. The Mishna Berurah says one should say Shma as early as possible, so a dispute as to the latest time should not make such a difference.

Comment: @N.T. And there's also nothing to lose by reading it late if you missed the earlier time so there's no proof that the bottom line opinion isn't like the earlier time. The point is just everyone should ask their rabbi for a ruling since Judaism isn't monolithic.

Answer (score 0):

Rav Moshe Fienstien holds that the minhag decides the halacha. (Few sources' 1 Dibros Moshe Brachos 22a)Thus the minhag was like the Gra therefore the halacha is like him. It's only a chumra to fulfill the Magen Avrahams shita as well.

Comment: Can you provide a source?

Comment: @israelreader there is a dibros somewhere that proves it. However I heard it from one of his talmidim.

Comment: So why did he bother writing all those responsa analysing classical halachic sources?

Comment: @doubleaa what are you reffering to?

Comment: It's in Igros Moshe (both Shlomy's answer and AA's quip). Look it up in Yad Moshe.

Comment: I find it difficult to accept the assertion that "Minhag" supersedes the entire Halachic process, and is the deciding factor in Halacha. Therefore, unless you can provide an authoritative source for such a notion, I see no reason to even consider it. I add, tongue in cheek, that many people have a "minhag" to speak "Lashon Hara". Does this now create a justification for such activity?

Comment: @israelreader i will explain to you what he means. That when there's a machlokes between conflicting shitas. And one is the majority even, if the minhag is to be lenient,  the halacha follows it. He has a proofs to this yesod. However I'm not sure why you bothered by this so much if many things we do is based off this. For example ashkenazi women make a bracha on time bound mitzvos, and we don't say safek brachos lihakel.. we're lenient by chadash, not everyone puts on tefillin chol hamoed... this concept is found throughout...

Comment: @Shlomy It's completely circular to prove that the halacha must be like the minhag because the minhag is to follow the minhag. That's just the definition of minhag. Your cases are irrelevant (and disputable).

Comment: Unless you provide a source for the alleged statement from Rav Moshe Feinstein, I see no value in discussing phantom quotes.